# How to add content from Laravel to Firestore?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Adding content from Laravel to Firebase database as follows:

```
$postRef = $this->database->getReference($this->tablename)->push($postData);
```

But I don't know how to add content from Laravel to Firestore. This is my Firestore:
[image]

This is how Laravel looks like:

[image]
These are my codes:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Firebase;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Firestore;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Firestore $firestore)
    {
        $this->firestore = $firestore;
        $this->tablename = 'kategoriler';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('firebase.contact.index');
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view('firebase.contact.create');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $postData = [
            'comment' => $request->comment,
            'iD' => $request->iD,
            'imgUrl' => $request->imgUrl,
            'lat' => $request->lat,
            'location' => $request->location,
            'lon' => $request->lon,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'youtubeId' => $request->youtubeId,

        ];

        $postRef = $this->app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection($this->tablename)->Document(0)->collection('bolgeler')->push($postData);
        if($postRef)
        {
            return redirect('contacts')->with('durum','İçerik eklendi.');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('contacts')->with('durum','İçerik eklenemedi.');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add data to bolgeler collection with auto document name, you can do this :

```
$postRef = $this->app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('bolgeler')->newDocument()->set($postData);
```

or :

```
$posref = $this->firestore->database()->collection('bolgeler')->newDocument()->set($postData);
```

when you nedd add specific name :

```
$postRef = $this->app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('bolgeler')->document('id001')->set($postData);
```

or:

```
$posref = $this->firestore->database()->collection('bolgeler')->document('id001)->set($postData);
```